# How to return data from database

Tags: vb.net

I have the next code for return a value from database

```
If Not IsDBNull(rsObtenerDatosNit("porteria").Value) AndAlso CBool(rsObtenerDatosNit("porteria").Value) = False Then
    porteria = False
    nPorteria.Checked = False
Else
    porteria = True
    nPorteria.Checked = True
End If
```

The field "porteria" in database it is bit and is with a value of 0 but does not enter to the first condition Where a checkbox with a false value is assigned if not that is entering the Else condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
If Not IsDBNull(rsObtenerDatosNit("porteria")) Then
     If CBool(rsObtenerDatosNit("porteria").Value) = False Then
          porteria = False
          nPorteria.Checked = False
     Else
          porteria = True
          nPorteria.Checked = True
     End If
End If
```

You could even add an Else statement to the first If logic, where you show an error stating the field does not exist.  But you need to be doing the IsDbNull check on the field itself, not the value of the field.

Comment: You could eliminate that inner If statement with `porteria = CBool(rsObtenerDatosNit("porteria").Value)` followed by `nPorteria.Checked = porteria`.